# Converting UST TO EST Time zone issue Synapse vs Databricks?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-synapse

I have requirement to convert the UST TO EST Timezone in sysnapse and databricks .In Syanpse it is working fine and in the databricks the data is previewing as yesterdays data

Synapse output:

[image]

Databricks output:

[image]

Comment: Insted of `from_utc_timestamp` use `to_utc_timestamp` it will Returns the timestamp in expr in a different timezone as UTC.

Answer (score 1):

In Spark SQL, function `from_utc_timestamp(timestamp, timezone)` converts UTC timestamp to a timestamp in the given time zone. function `to_utc_timestamp(timestamp, timezone)` converts timestamp in a given time zone to UTC timestamp.

I have also tried and got similar results.
[image]

when we pass value as a date it and when we convert it into timestamp it by default takes `00.00.00` values for `hr:mm:ss` respectively and EST is behind of UTC because of it when converting to EST you are getting 1 day less in conversion.

For your desired output you can use `to_utc_timestamp(timestamp, timezone)`

[image]